# To edit or not to edit?

Tags: discussion

I happened to look at the front page and saw an interesting (to me) question which was appropriately closed as seeking personal medical advice.
I edited [the post](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/15803/169) to remove that aspect.

I haven't been following the shift in the site or the progress towards that change, so I don't know if this is now on topic or not. Clearly it's a layman's question. It's not very complicated, but it's very common. It tends to be brushed off by doctors with a brusque, "Stop biting them," or advising the patient to apply bitter polish to the nails. A nice, from-the-literature answer might be helpful.

On the other hand, if this were actually a physician to physician site, would asking what has been successful in nail-biting patients be any different?

I did read the *scope* Q and As, but don't know how or if they are being implemented.

Or not.

What does the community think? Does it fit with what the goals of the site are now?

Comment: I think it fits with the orientation of the site, but my only problem is that there are maybe 7 words (And most of those are "is" and "it") left from the original question, which essentially makes it your own question. If the OP agrees, I can reopen it, however.

Comment: As far as the implementation, I am waiting on an email/post from the CM team regarding what they discussed in their meetings.

Comment: @JohnP - lol! Sorry... :P

Answer (score 3):

I saw that edit pop up in the Review queue and actually opened a tab to rollback the edit, but since JohnP has commented on it aware of the edit I thought a discussion would be better. I haven’t found this meta post until know, though. Might be worth posting a link underneath the post in the future.

The problem is (in my opinion) that the edit significantly alters the question: The part of coming in contact with water and speeding up the healing processes have been removed, and parts that actually feel like an answer („Considered cosmetic [...]“) have been included.

Don’t get me wrong, the edit definitely improved the post by a great extend, but maybe we should leave this post closed, rollback and anongoodnurse or anyone can just ask the edit as a question. That doesn’t tamper with OP‘s intentions but provides them a good answer of they should ever come back this site.

Here is a Meta Discussion regarding a similar fashioned edit:
[Should I edit or comment to an answer to make it more elaborate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157827/353950)

Comment: He mentioned "ugly"; I considered "cosmetic" to be the same. :)

Comment: Good idea to link to the meta question, thanks.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I was referring to this: *Unless nail biting is severe, it is considered to be mostly a cosmetic problem, complicated by the risk of infection (paronychia, herpetic whitlow, etc.)*. This to me feels like a partial answer. Again, the post as  stands  right now is of great quality and what I‘d love to see on the front page, but we are entering dangerous territory if we tamper with people‘s posts too much. The „easy“ solution would be to revert the edit and post a new question (=: the edit)

Comment: That's fine with me, and why I asked in Meta before even voting to reopen. I don't want to open a question that the community wants to keep closed, feels was improperly edited, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Any question can be potentially re-opened in this fashion, but this becomes very old very quickly.

Sure I can think of a bazillion questions that people might ask that might be useful but what's the point?  I'm not seeking to turn this site into a dump for my 40+ years of medical knowledge here.

We're looking for good questions from good users, and we're more interested in the latter than the former since we can easily do that ourselves.  And once we have the users the hope is that the good questions follow on from there.  Many hands make light work.

So, my vote is close and forget.

Comment: Aren't you in the generative stage yet?